# C# to close this "Close the program" popup

Tags: c#

We automate everything with Windows desktop, and periodically some 3rd-party apps pop up warning/exception boxes, while we can detect and send key code (Enter) to close those with "OK" button, same method can bring these to forefront but key code (Enter, or Alt+F4) never be able to close them simulating

1. hitting Enter as "Close the program" is highlighted as default.
2. Alt+F4 to close it as a window.

[image]

Here is the code

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
{
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        if (up)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
        }
        else
        {
            keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        }
}

Process[] pp = Process.GetProcesses();    
    ... // qualifying the right handle assign to "p", debug shows it select the popup and set forefront (with focus).
        hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
        //Thread.Sleep(100);  // thought needs some time to send key code before it's fully brought to forefront, but not matter.
        PressKey(Keys.Enter, false);
        PressKey(Keys.Enter, true);
        //Thread.Sleep(100);
        PressKey(Keys.Enter, false);
        PressKey(Keys.Enter, true);
        // following not working either
        //PressKey(Keys.Alt, false);
        //PressKey(Keys.F4, false);
        //PressKey(Keys.Alt, true);
        //PressKey(Keys.F4, true);
```

During debugging, when they are brought to forefront and keycode won't work, manually hit ENTER or Alt+F4 do work. I've googled and tried whatever found in SO.

Comment: Where are you getting `p` for `p.MainWindowHandle` are you sure you have the handle of the correct process? That dialog is not from your programs process it is from a separate windows process.

Comment: p is the `Process[] pp = Process.GetProcesses(); ... foreach (Process p in pp)`

Comment: You probably need to get the window handle for "WerFault.exe" not the process which crashed; it does not own that error window.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain pretty sure that's the right handle as I can see the popup brought to forefront just like those traditional msgbox having a "OK" button, but key code not working.

Comment: Please update your question [with a edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50591114/edit) and include all of the code you use to get `p`. Just because it is bringing it to the forfront when you try to make that call does not mean it is the correct process.

Comment: Did you consider just using Group Policy to disable this window instead? https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsErrorReporting::WerDoNotShowUI

Comment: @Jeb50 you are missing the point. I think the bug in your code is in the code your removed in the `...`. You are selecting the wrong process, We need to see everything that you hid with `...`to help you. Your problem is in there.

Comment: @DarkFalcon could be an option, for now want to do whatever DEV can do programatically, may be a last resort for OPS.

Comment: That box is coming from windows. You should be able to get away by killing that process directly. No keystroke required.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain did you see my comment that I can see the popup being selected and brought to forefront? Also this qualifying a process assigning to `p` was working for msgbox with `OK` button.

Comment: @Steve you're correct, `p.kill()` is destructive and may not release all resources properly.

Comment: @odyss-jii will try.

Comment: @Jeb50 When you see that popup it means the 3rd party program encountered a unhandled exception and has been forcefully killed by windows already. Resource might or might not be released properly and you have no control over it. Killing that windows process has nothing to do with your 3rd party program

Comment: @Jeb50 did you see my comment where I said *"Just because it is bringing it to the forfront when you try to make that call does not mean it is the correct process."* please show us the code

Comment: @ScottChamberlain kill() and WerFault.exe are good, thanks.